# Cómo puedo agregar una clave secundaria en mysql?

Tags: mysql

[![ayuda con las siguientes tablas son en mysql][1]][1]

Tengo que agregar claves secundaria y registros alas tablas

Comment: Usando `FOREING KEY(campo)` para claves secundarias y para registros, `INSERT INTO`. Por otro lado, deberías leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), puesto que una pregunta como la que has planteado podría ser cerrada, para más dudas acude al [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).